# How do I make/compile a single .ascx file from a .ascx.cs file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to make a small change in a .ascx.cs file and make it into a .ascx file. I have no idea how to make the .ascx file and so I'm looking for very rudimentary help. Noob alert, I have no experience or training with C#, asp.net development so nothing is too basic.

Some background/details. I'm supporting an off-the-self web application in IIS, .Net 4.0, with SQL server db. It supports custom WebParts which can be loaded into the system and run within the context of the application. 99% of the site is managed by the built-in CRM except for a few pages (written by someone who is no longer available) that accepts 5 search terms, runs an SQL query and sends the result set to another custom webpart for formatting and display to the user.

I have to modify the source file by commenting out some code that builds part of an SQL statement and re-upload it to the application's CRM system. This will change the query terms, but not alter the schema of the data returned so this won't require any downstream changes.

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed and can open/view the LOOKUP.ascx.cs file, but can't figure out how to make that single file into the LOOKUP.ascx file. All I can find on disk are the individual files, no Solution or Project files. I don't know if 'Build' is what I'm looking for but it is grayed-out.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: I figured this out. All I needed to do was edit the .ascx.cs file on disk and IIS will pickup the changes when the page is loaded in a browser. Moderators: feel free to lock or delete this as it will be of limited value to anyone.

Comment: This was of value as I had exactly the same question. You should answer this yourself and accept it as the solution. Cheers!